# How do you do your big exports / imports?

Tags: migration, import, export, bulk-import

I have a big client (50k orders, 70k customers), I'm working today on the migration of his site on a new version of WordPress on a new server.

I need to export and import the products / customers / orders on the new WordPress without any ID modification.

Problem, after working on the site I realize that the import is impossible because various customer and order IDs are already taken.

How do you do exports / imports like this?

Do you have a magic solution? ;)

I have already done dozens of migrations on other e-commerce CMS like PrestaShop, Magento... I am shocked by the way Woocommerce works on this point which seems to me to be the basis.

Thanks to all !

Comment: what do you mean by taken by other native WP functions? Are you trying to import into an existing site, and if so, how are you trying to import? There are lots of plugins, tools, commands, both inside and outside WordPress for importing/exporting, be as specific as you can even if it seems obvious/patronising. Also 3rd party plugin dev support is offtopic here so if this requires WooCommerce specific advice then it will be offtopic

Comment: I've tried the "Product Import Export Plugin for WooCommerce" plugin and a few others. My issue is that I'm building a new website from scratch while the current one still runs and sells, so if I try to import products, orders, custommers, etc, from the old website to the new it obviously tells me that primary indexes are conflicting. I'd like a solution that would be able to transfer all these datas from one Wordpress/Woocommerce to another seamlessly with no conflicts.

Comment: hmmm so you are not clearing out/resetting the target environments database and importing over the top and expecting existing content to be ignored/replaced? That's not how most imports are going to work, particularly if you're using any method that uses SQL. If it's help with a plugin then you would need to ask their support, plugins such as Product import export plugin for WC are off topic here and not in this stacks scope and you can't ask about those plugins here. Otherwise what you're suggesting is fundamentally impossible as long as you continue to require that new IDs do not change